# Why is docker compose saying no such file or directory?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple vue + django project and I want to be able to containerize this project with docker but I've run into some issues. I have dockerfiles and docker compose files in each subfolder - frontend and backend - and if I cd into either I can successfully start each individual project using docker compose with no problems.

However, I want to be able to run one single docker compose command that can create both images simultaneously. I currently have a docker compose file in the root directory of the project and I am including the compose files and referencing them in the services. It works fine with just the vue service but gives me an error when I include the django services. Error code is this:

`failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2369903057/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

The django project was created using cookiecutter so it has everything I need in the project. Here is a simple version of my file structure:

```
  - api 
      - compose 
        - Dockerfile
    - docker-compose.yml
  - frontend
    - Dockerfile
    - docker-compose.yml
  - docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my backend compose file:

```
volumes:
  api_local_postgres_data: {}
  api_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: api_local_django
    container_name: api_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: api_production_postgres
    container_name: api_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - api_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - api_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: api_local_docs
    container_name: api_local_docs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./api:/app/api:z
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    command: /start-docs
```

Here's the root compose:

```
include:
  - ./frontend/docker-compose.yml
  - ./api/docker-compose.yml

services:
  frontend_vue:
    build: ./frontend
    depends_on:
      - vue-ui

  backend_django:
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - django

  backend_postgres:
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  backend_docs:
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - docs
```

Comment: Can you include the full project directory tree ?

Comment: In the last file, you're declaring new services like `backend_django` that independently build new images out of for example the `api` directory looking for the Dockerfile in that directory; in addition to the `django` container in the `backend` directory.  Is that intended?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I initially tried to keep the service names the same but it returns an error saying ```imported compose file defines conflicting service``` so to get around that I rename the services. This worked for me with the frontend vue service.

Comment: @godd0t heres my project repo. You can view the entire structure here 
 https://github.com/baconkev000/docker_issue

Comment: Do you need to redefine a new service at all in the top-level Compose file, or is the definition in the imported Compose file enough?  What's the difference between `django` in the `backend` directory, and `django_backend` in the top-level file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare the services in in the root `docker-compose.yml` file.
For instance, when you include the `api/docker-compose.yml` in your root `docker-compose.yml` file, all the services defined in the `api/docker-compose.yml` file are loaded into the root compose application model. Therefore, the services are already available in the root compose application, and you don't need to declare it again in the root `docker-compose.yml` file.

So, the `docker-compose.yml` files would look like:

**root `docker-compose.yml`:**

```yaml
include:
  - ./frontend/docker-compose.yml
  - ./api/docker-compose.yml
```

**`api/docker-compose.yml`:**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  ...
```

Comment: this worked!! thank you so much! I didn't realize it was that simple!!